# Существует ли в языке C возможность создать массив с элементами типа struct

Tags: c, массивы, структуры, struct

Можно ли в языке Си заполнить двухмерный массив элементами типа struct, если да, то как и как потом при поиске по массиву их находить? Мой пример правильный?

```
typedef struct {
        'trash_t field[14][21]';
        int player_order;
        int moves_num;
    } gamestate_t;

    typedef struct {
        int coord;
        char direction;
        int speed;
        char parameters[4];
    } 'trash_t;'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без проблем. Например:

```
typedef struct {
    int coord;
    char direction;
    int speed;
    char parameters[4];
} trash_t;

typedef struct {
    trash_t field[14][21];
    int player_order;
    int moves_num;
} gamestate_t;


int main()
{
    gamestate_t g[5];
    g[1].field[3][8].parameters[1] = 'a';
}
```